# ViewModel + LiveData in Fragment, How to keep data of the ListItemFragment when navigate back from ItemDetailFragment

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

At the bottom in the onCreateView of ListItemFragment, i make a network call to get all items. like this:

```
viewmodel.getAllItems()
```

Then, observe the data to populate items to the RecyclerView. 
I'm using Navigation Architecture Component to navigate to ItemDetailFragment when User click on each Item.
The problem is, when i hit back button, ListItemFragment's onCreateView call again, then viewmodel.getAllItems() also call again.
So, what i want is prevent call getAllItems() again, and keep current position of RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourItemType yourItems; //define this as global field
```

In onCreateView;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle 
  if(yourItems == null){
     yourItems = viewmodel.getAllItems();
  }
}
```

Comment: my concern is, it has many boilerplate code to check global variables, or check inside LiveData's Observe right? 
Using ViewModel + LiveData with Activity, we don't have to do that :(